# Rigid bodies sliding off slopes

Tags: physics, 3d, movement, rigidbody, godot-3

Kinematic bodies have a simple class that makes the player not slide on slopes, but for rigid bodies? I tried using rays and areas, either to lock the player on an axis or to just straight up disable gravity when the player touches the floor, bur this doesn't work.

It is very important to prevent sliding since I need this for a climbing mechanic. The climbing already works, the only problem is, imagine being able to climb up a 90 degree wall, but slide off terrain steeper than 40 degrees.

The best I managed to do so far is to set movement in Y axis to 0 while the player is on a slope. For some reason it does slow the sliding, actually makes it so slow that is hard to notice, but the player still slides down.

Comment: Idk if this is a solution: try enabling rough in the material override of the rigid body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just done this in godot 4. Essentially instead of projecting gravity straight down, you detect the normal of the floor and project along that. If you do this your character should stay stationary. I also set the physics material to rough and the friction to max as a precaution.

I based most of this on the following unity tutorials for creating a rigid body based character: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/movement/ (in particular https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/movement/physics/#3 for slope handling).

It should be reasonably straightforward to convert what is there to godot. At least with godot 4 I haven't had any trouble findng the right calls etc.